# Memberpress: Can I add a second email address?

Tags: plugins, membership

I'm trying to send a duplicate payment confirmation email with Memberpress after a successful payment.

Corporate subscribers are requesting a cc: payment confirmation email to be sent to Accounting / Accounts Payable.

I've looked pretty carefully through the MemberPress documentation and it looks like there's no way to add additional cc emails through the Memberpress interface.

Before I dive in to a hacky fix... is there a best way to do this?

I'm thinking first I'll add a custom user field for "Send Copy of Invoice to".

And then check for that field and if it exists, fire off an additional email.

Or am I missing a simpler, or more efficient, or smarter solution?

Also -- I use Stripe for payments. Is this better to do at the Stripe level?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: did you tried using mail@mail.com **,** mail2@mail.com?

Comment: I was under the impression that wasn't supported. Is it? 'Will try. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishwa FYI That doesn't work. Also confirmed by Memberpress support.

Comment: if it's a plugin, then best place for support will be developer's forums/helpdesk

Comment: That's not a helpful comment. I'm asking here too.  As have the thousands of others who have asked Memberpress, WooCommerce and BuddyPress questions on Stackexchange. This is a development question, not a usage question.

Comment: WooCommerce and BuddyPress are somewhat very popular and widely used. I'm not **telling** you, but suggesting you, because from there you'll get better response